# Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to pass in a destination View Struct to another view, but the code won't compile.

I want to pass in some struct that conforms to the view protocol, so it can be used in a navigation button destination, but I can't seem to get it to compile. I've tried setting the type of destination to _View as well. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

```swift
struct AnimatingCard : View {

    var title, subtitle : String
    var color : Color
    var destination : View

    init(title : String, subtitle: String, color: Color, destination : View){
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.color = color
        self.destination = destination


    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationButton(destination: destination) {
    ...
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If there’s no common concrete type that all the views used in `destination` will be, you should use the [`AnyView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/anyview) struct to obtain a type-erased concrete `View` conforming object.

ETA:

`AnyView` has an initializer declared as `init<V>(_ view: V) where V : View`, so wherever you were creating your `AnimatingCard` before you should now write:

```
AnimatingCard(title: title, subtitle: subtitle, color: color, destination: AnyView(view))
```

Alternatively, you could make `AnimatingCard`'s initializer generic over all `View`-conforming types and do the `AnyView` conversion inside the initializer, like this:

```
init<V>(title : String, subtitle: String, color: Color, destination : V) where V: View {
    self.title = title
    self.subtitle = subtitle
    self.color = color
    self.destination = AnyView(destination)
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more? It's my understanding that no view will have a concrete "type" as views are structs not types, which conform to view. I'm just trying to pass in a destination to a nav button that is a variable, which depends on the button the user selected.

Comment: What I mean is that if you had something like `struct DetailView: View { ... }`, and every `AnimatingCard` had a destination that was a `DetailView`, you could just use that as the type of `destination`. In Swift, types defined by `struct`, `class`, and `enum` are "concrete" types. The `AnyView` type is a special `struct` in SwiftUI which can wrap any `View`-conforming type and hide the different underlying types.

Comment: Okay thank you for clarifying a bit. What I don't understand is how would I get around this error after changing the type of destination to 'AnyView': '...View.Type' is not convertible to 'AnyView'

Comment: @Jumhyn You are a legend! Thanks for this